# How Should I have Constructed this page.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm working on a website. I'm usng page.php to control all the pages even though they have different categories. All was ok on my local server (XAMPP), I could view all the pages, but when I uploaded online, I got parse error while trying to view the pages.

I did not want to create individual files for all the pages so I decided to place all in page.php using the `if ( is_page( page_id )`

Here is the error I got:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /----/woodclef.com/wp-content/themes/woodclef/page.php on line 1

Checkout the site via: www.woodclef.com Password is 12345678

**Edited**

I have a cleaner codes now and the errors are gone but no post is showing even when the category ids and page ids are true. Can anyone help figure out what could be wrong?

```
<?php 
//Highlights
if ( is_page( 10 ) ) {          

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'cat' => 5
    );
    $sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = 0;
    while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post();  
     $count++;
        if ($count == 1) : 
        get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' ); 

        elseif ($count == 2) : 
          get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' ); 

        else :
           get_template_part( 'pages/common_template' );     

        endif;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
} 
//News 
if ( is_page( 144 ) ) {         

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'cat' => 6
    );
    $sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = 0;
    while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post(); 
         $count++;
        if ($count == 1) : 
            get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' ); 

        elseif ($count == 2) : 
            get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' );

      else : 
             get_template_part( 'pages/common_template' );     

        endif;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: I recoment use php famework like laravel. Use routers

Comment: Why are you always opening and closing the php tag? It's absolutely unnecessary and only leads to errors.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois What should I do? Did you mean I should remove the opening tag at the top and the closing tag down below?

Comment: Remove the ones in between (there are a lot there). If you dont have anything else after the last php closing tag, you can remove it too. Generally only one php opening tag is necessary, the one at the top.

Comment: You do know that the `is_page( 10 )` and `is_page( 144 )` will be true and all your loops will be executed on every request, as long as those ID's exist as pages in the database? If I understand you correctly, i think you mean to check if the current request is any of those ID's and then do your while loops?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to write a clean code and see if there is any error.
 Try below code in your page.php

```
<?php
//Highlights
if ( is_page( 10 ) ) {          

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'cat' => 5
        );
        $sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $count = 0;
        if($sticky_query->have_posts()):
        while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post();  
         $count++;
            if ($count == 1) : 
            get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' ); 

            elseif ($count == 2) : 
              get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' ); 

            else :
               get_template_part( 'pages/common_template' );     

            endif;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
        endif;          
} 


//News
if ( is_page( 144 ) ) {         

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'cat' => 6
        );
        $sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $count = 0;
        if($sticky_query->have_posts()):
        while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post(); 
             $count++;
            if ($count == 1) : 
                get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' ); 

            elseif ($count == 2) : 
                get_template_part( 'pages/common_template_a' );

          else : 
                 get_template_part( 'pages/common_template' );     

            endif;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();     
        endif;

 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @LalKumarRai for pointing out my mistakes. The codes are cleaner now but no post is shown even when the category ids and page ids are true. Can you help me figure out why?

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($sticky_query );echo "</pre>";die();                       use above code just below    $sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );  and check for posts

Comment: I did just that but no post was returned

Comment: that means there is no post related to that category or something is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Passing post_type in your argument of WP_Query might solve the issue.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' =>'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'cat' => 5
    );
```

Comment: It didn't work sir. I tried this and it shows: `if ( is_page( 10 ) ) {
     echo "hello";
   }`

Comment: Have you added post_type in your argument and tried?